# How to get a Telegram bot about or description using telethon

Tags: python, telethon

When I get the history chat message with a bot I can't see the "hello" message ("What can this bot do?") in the return message_context. How can I get it?

```
message_context = client.send_message(bot_name, '/start')
for message in client.iter_messages(bot_name):
   print("{}".format(bot_name))
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`GetFullUserRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/users/get_full_user.html) to fetch the [`bot_info`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/bot_info.html) attribute of the [`UserFull`](https://tl.telethon.dev/constructors/user_full.html) instance:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(bot_name))
    bot_info = result.bot_info
    print(bot_info)
    print(bot_info.description)
```